# Create list of enums and pass it to a method

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I created a method which takes an enum and transforms it in a Dictionary where each int is associated with the name (as string) of the enum

```
// Define like this
public static Dictionary<int, string> getDictionaryFromEnum<T>()
{
   List<T> commandList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList();
   Dictionary<int, string> finalList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
   foreach (T command in commandList)
   {
    finalList.Add((int)(object)command, command.ToString());
   }
 return finalList;
 }
```

(ps. yes, I have a double cast but the application is meant to be a very cheap-and-dirty C#-enum to Javascript-enum converter).

This can be easily used like this

```
private enum _myEnum1 { one = 1001, two = 1002 };
private enum _myEnum2 { one = 2001, two = 2002 };
// ... 
var a = getDictionaryFromEnum<_myEnum1>();
var b = getDictionaryFromEnum<_myEnum2>();
```

Now, I was wondering whether I could create a list of enums to use for a series of calls to iterate my calls.

**This was in the original question: [Why can't I call this?]**

What should I do to be able to create a call like this one?

```
List<Type> enumsToConvertList = new List<Type>();
enumsToConvertList.Add(typeof(_myEnum1));
enumsToConvertList.Add(typeof(_myEnum2));
// this'll be a loop
var a = getDictionaryFromEnum<enumsToConvertList.ElementAt(0)>();
```

Comment: Because the types used in generics are not the same as `System.Type`s.

Comment: What would be the type of `a`?

Comment: because the generics support only static type. You are trying to put type object into type parameter in generic method. Try to rewrite getDictionaryFromEnum with Type object

Comment: Thanks for the advise and sorry for the commotion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't specify generic argument type at runtime (well, without reflection). So, simply create non-generic method, which accepts argument of `Type` type:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> getDictionaryFromEnum(Type enumType)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<object>()
               .ToDictionary(x => (int)x, x => x.ToString());
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Type> enumsToConvertList = new List<Type>();
enumsToConvertList.Add(typeof(_myEnum1));
enumsToConvertList.Add(typeof(_myEnum2));

var a = getDictionaryFromEnum(enumsToConvertList[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks lazy, I'll accept your answer. And I'll remove the 'Advanced knowledge' from the C# slot on my CV.

Comment: @malber maybe you just need to read several articles about generics and Linq, instead of modifying your cv :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I call this?

In that case, you're passing in `System.Type`, which is different than the generic specifier, which is a compile time value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate method that takes the Enum as a generic and returns a dictionary of all the members

```
 public static Dictionary<int, string> ToDictionary<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof (T);
        if (!type.IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("Only Enum types allowed");
        return Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>().ToDictionary(value => (int) Enum.Parse(type, value.ToString()), value => value.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, the type parameters to a generic must be known at compile time.

You are trying to pass a runtime `System.Type` *object* as a generic type specifier, which is not possible.

---

As for what you're trying to accomplish, your method does not actually need to be generic, since you are always returning a `Dictionary<int, string>`. Try passing the `Type` as a parameter to the method instead, as @lazyberezovsky demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to the type later on:

```
List<Type> enumsToConvertList = new List<Type>();
enumsToConvertList.Add(_myEnum1);
var a = getDictionaryFromEnum<typeof(enumsToConvertList.ElementAt(0))>();
```